# Monitor becomes unreliable after sleep or startup (USB-C thunderbolt to HDMI)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I'm trying to connect my laptop to 2 external monitors (Win11, Radeon graphics).
One monitor is connected directly through the laptop's HDMI output.
The second monitor is connected using a "USB-C thunderbolt to HDMI hub"

After starting/waking up the computer, the monitor connected via USB-C is often black. It takes quite a few plugging + unplugging to get it working. Swapping the 2 monitors still results in the thunderbolt hub monitor being black at startup.

Is there any way to solve this permanently? I don't want to plug/unplug monitors all the time.

Comment: If you set your power plan to "HIgh Performance" do you still get the same behaviour? In addition to this you should find within power plan there is "Advanced Power Plan" settings. In there you will find "USB Settings" where "USB selective suspend setting" is default to enabled. If you disable this, does it still behave the same way?

Comment: There's only "Balanced" option available in Power Options and no "USB Settings" in the expandable tree (Only have HDD, Desktop Background, PCIE, Processor, Display, and Battery)

Comment: Found a way to get USB Settings from Power Options via the regedit. Unfortunately, that didn't seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: When the monitor is black, is it still visible within windows display settings?

Comment: yes the monitor is visible in display settings.

Comment: If you're willing to try it there might be a way to "wake up" that monitor automatically with a program and script. Not sure if it will work. The program is called ChangeScreenResolution.exe. It's used for adjusting screen resolutions via the commandline, but if you were to call this program with a script that launches every time you log in it might just wake up that monitor. It's more of a workaround than a solution. That does interest you?

Comment: http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/

Comment: Let me know if you want to try this and i can write a batch script that calls the function i think will work

Comment: thanks. it does work - just need to change the res to something else and then back after it wakes up. Something like this `.\ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1280 /h=720 /d=1
.\ChangeScreenResolution.exe /w=1920 /h=1080 /d=1` A bit of a dirty trick but just need to execute this everytime the PC wakes up.

Comment: Cool, so to execute that automatically you can copy those commands into a .txt file and then rename the .txt to .bat (executable batch script)

Comment: Then you can copy the .bat file to this location: in the run menu type: shell:common startup

Comment: Anything copied into that folder will automatically launch on startup for all users. The question is, does it work on "waking" from sleep. I'm not sure.

Comment: You'll want to combine those two commands into a chain using && to join them together. That way they will run one after the other inside a single .bat file

Comment: For reference: & means do this command next even if the previous command fails. && means do this command next only if the previous command succeeds

Comment: It is indeed a dirty workaround, but if it means your monitor will wake up for now then at least you have the two monitors working. I would leave this question open though because it's not a final solution. We may come across someone who it educated on video signalling and monitors. It might be worth looking at the energy saving settings on the monitor itself perhaps? If the monitors are identical model compare the good monitor settings with the sleepy monitor settings. Check every single menu and sub menu for subtle differences and make the sleepy monitor settings match the good monitor.